# Slow query time when using sum() on related table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (users and xp_points). I need to get the total sum of each user's xp points. But my query seems to be very slow (380 ms). My database is quite big. I tried to create a column on users table called total_xp_points and then the query time went down to 4.6 ms only.

But I don't want to manually have to update each user's total xp points. Is there a way to optimize this query for speed?

**users table**

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+
| id |  fullname   | total_xp_points |
+----+-------------+-----------------+
|  1 | John Adams  |              22 |
|  2 | Will Smith  |               0 |
|  3 | Bob McGee   |             125 |
|  4 | Andy Briggs |               0 |
|  5 | Linda James |              20 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+
```

**xp_points table**

```
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
| id | user_id |    date    | xp_points |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 | 2019-01-05 |        17 |
|  2 |       1 | 2019-03-07 |         5 |
|  3 |       3 | 2019-03-07 |         0 |
|  4 |       3 | 2019-01-08 |       125 |
|  5 |       5 | 2019-01-19 |        20 |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
```

This query took **380.711 ms** (much slower)

```
SELECT
    users.id as user_id,
    users.fullname,
    sum(xp_points.xp_points) AS total_xp_points
FROM
    users
INNER JOIN xp_points
    ON users.id = xp_points.user_id
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    users.fullname
HAVING
    SUM(xp_points.xp_points) > 3
LIMIT 100
```

Result

```
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
| user_id |  fullname   | total_xp_points |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
|       1 | John Adams  |              22 |
|       3 | Bob McGee   |             125 |
|       5 | Linda James |              20 |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
```

This next query takes only **4.641 ms** (*much faster but I have to manually maintain total_xp_points on users table which I don't want*)

```
SELECT
    users.id as user_id,
    fullname,
    total_xp_points
FROM users
WHERE
    total_xp_points > 3
limit 100
```

It gives the same result as first query (*but faster execution time*)

```
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
| user_id |  fullname   | total_xp_points |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
|       1 | John Adams  |              22 |
|       3 | Bob McGee   |             125 |
|       5 | Linda James |              20 |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN` of the queries.

Comment: You have "join", "group by" and "sum" and you expect it to perform the same way as a simple query? Cannot have it both ways.

Comment: You could add a trigger for when xp_points is updated, it also automatically updates the total_xp_points fields in the other table.

Comment: @RomanHocke here is the explain https://pastebin.com/UgePFhCV

Comment: I thought maybe there was a way to optimize it.

Comment: Your query looks OK. Have you created indexes on users.id & xp_points.user_id i.e the join columns?

Comment: @MartinZeltin: as Krishna suggested, make sure you have index on userid in both tables. Also, remove users.fullname from group by

Comment: @MartinZeltin Even with the best indexes the query will become increasingly slower over time. I would avoid running it every second. Instead I would use a trigger to update the `total_xp_points` column on point changes, and I would query the `users` table alone. Alternatively you could run it once an hour and create a temp table with it. Then you could query from it only, considering the result can be 60-minute stale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem may be the `GROUP BY`. You could try selecting a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id,
       users.fullname,
       (SELECT SUM(xp_points) FROM xp_points WHERE xp_points.user_id = users.id) AS total_xp_points
  FROM users
HAVING total_xp_points > 3
 LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! My query time dropped from 380 ms to 6 ms. I don't understand why GROUP BY was causing such problems.

Comment: It could be because the `GROUP BY` has to happen before the `HAVING` clause and therefore causing more calculations to be necessary before the `LIMIT` could happen. I in no way claim to know all the intricacies of the query planner but I think that is what was happening. Either way, glad I could help! :)